# How to identify UDP based DoS

Tags: networking, server, games, iptables, firewall

I'm running Counter-strike game server on 27015 UDP port. I'm using Amazon AWS to host game server.

I have added only my friend's IP into security group so rest of the traffic is always blocked.

My enemy is using IP spoofing trick. He is spoofing my friend's IP and sending UDP flood.

He sends it from 3-4 IPs.

What I'm currently doing is that, I'm capturing IPs in TCPdump and blocking manually.

Is it possible to get those IPs using shell script or something so I can block that IP.

Thanks!

Comment: as this question is not specific to Ubuntu it would best be asked in Unix/Linux or Information Security instead of AskUbuntu.

Comment: Since UDP is stateless, once my friend is in the server and if I remove his IP, he still stays in the server.

Comment: Thanks, please edit your question and include the tcpdump command you are using and a sample of the output so that we know what you are looking for. It seems like a script would be simple using grep and awk but I don't know what parameters to look for (how do you know what IPs to flag). Thanks!

Comment: you should be able to do what you want directly at iptables level. However I still don't understand the distinction between your friend and the spoofing bad guy. Everything @mchid asked for would help. i disagree that MAC address can be used, unless everything involved, good/bad guys, are on the same sub-net. MAC addresses do not cross sub-net boundaries.

Comment: @mchid : I'm just using basic tcpdump command to capture traffic and saving it in the .pcap file. I then analyze pcap file and I have to check if Packet length is more than 800 or not.

For example:    ```0.007450 192.168.168.2 â†’ 183.83.145.212 UDP 240 27015 â†’ 54491 Len=991```

Comment: @DougSmythies In this case I need to scan file and need to check if packet length is more than 800.

Comment: Decisions can be made based on packet length in iptables. It will take me time to write an answer. Give me a day. Which is good guy and which is bad guy? i.e. is your example packet from a good guy or bad guy?

Comment: Generally packet length is  from 40 to 400. So if packet length is more than 400 it means it is DoS attack.

Comment: The kind of script I was thinking of doesn't behave well with tcpdump.

Comment: Is there any way to get the IPs of DoS? Like getting DoSed from 10-15 Ips.

If I can get Ips I can remove them.

Comment: @Nihas Yes, I have updated the answer. The command shown will print all IPs that have packets that are above 400 in length in the terminal for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [very similar example](https://superuser.com/a/1414121/317065) that blocks packets of a specified length. Here, the packet length to block is 401 to 65535.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp --destination-port 27015 -m length --length 401:65535 -j DROP
```

---

**EDIT**:

If you just want to get the IPs, you can run the following command to have the IP addresses print in the terminal when they show up:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i wlp2s0 dst port 27015 -l 2>&1 | grep length | awk -F'[ .]' -v OFS="." '$NF >= 401 { print $4,$5,$6,$7 }'
```

This example is for wireless interface `wlp2s0` so change this to the correct device like `eth0` or whatever your network device is.

You can use this line as a script but it doesn't seem to behave well in a "for loop" or with extra pipes after this.